# Json object, convert json array into a json object in java

Tags: java, json

I have one json array like this

```
"values":[
  {
    "locale":"en_US",
    "source_key":"book_format",
    "value":"Hardback",
    "display_attr_name":"Book Format",
    "source_value":"Hardback",
    "isPrimary":"true"
  },
  {
    "isFacetValue":"true",
    "facet_version":"1.1",
    "locale":"en_US",
    "value":"Hardcover"
  }
]
```

I need to get the only the distinct keys from above json array

```
{
  "locale":"en_US",
  "source_key":"book_format",
  "value":"Hardback",
  "display_attr_name":"Book Format", 
  "source_value":"Hardback",
  "isPrimary":"true",
  "isFacetValue":"true",
  "facet_version":"1.1"
}
```

And the output will be in the form of jsonobject.

Comment: It is a string, use .replace("\s*[}{]\s*","") to get rid of the curly braces, then you can split("\"\s*,\s*\"") to split on the commas. That will give you a list of key-value pair strings. Loop through those and split("\"\s*:\s*\"") which will split the key from the value. you can then grab the [0] part which is the key, and put it into an ArrayList if the ArrayList doesn't already have it.

Comment: Parse the array to a List<Map<String, String>> using your JSON mapper. Put all the entries of the second map into the first one. Serialize the first map to JSON. Shoouldn't be more then 5 lines of code.

Comment: could you send the example code @JBNizet

Comment: How to concat the json array?

Comment: @k.parthiBan could you at least try doing it by yourself, given that you have pretty clear indicatipns now?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"values\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"locale\": \"en_US\"," +
    "      \"source_key\": \"book_format\"," +
    "      \"value\": \"Hardback\"," +
    "      \"display_attr_name\": \"Book Format\"," +
    "      \"source_value\": \"Hardback\"," +
    "      \"isPrimary\": \"true\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"isFacetValue\": \"true\"," +
    "      \"facet_version\": \"1.1\"," +
    "      \"locale\": \"en_US\"," +
    "      \"value\": \"Hardcover\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("values.mergeObjects()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "locale" : "en_US",
  "source_key" : "book_format",
  "value" : "Hardcover",
  "display_attr_name" : "Book Format",
  "source_value" : "Hardback",
  "isPrimary" : "true",
  "isFacetValue" : "true",
  "facet_version" : "1.1"
}
```